# Communicate Jira with java client using REST

Tags: jira

I have been reading the documentation that is in the page about Atlassian Jira.

I want to simply create a class in Eclipse to connect to Jira using Rest and get the name of an issue.

What do I need to install? I downloaded a jar of [this page](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client).

Answer (score 8):

#### First solution

If you are using Eclipse than it is simple.
Download the m2e plugin (Help -> Install new software --> Work with --> "[m2e plugin download link](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases)").

Then New -> Project ... -> Maven Project
In pom.xml add:

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>Version of the library you use</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

And use what is needed from https://studio.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JRJC/Tutorial.

#### Other solution

Or, if your only need is to get the issues name then you can make an HttpRequest to the REST url and parse the returned JSON.
How a REST response looks like: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9

See:
[How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)
,
[Decoding JSON format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715246/decoding-json-format-in-java)