# How can I Link Jira issues to an epic using java and REST

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I could create Jira issues through the Java and REST service by following this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650392/how-to-create-an-issue-in-jira-using-the-rest-api-java). Now I want to link the Jira issues to the already created epic in the project. How can I do this through java code.

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA REST API has it [defined here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4043).

From reading that [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/JeucUZNG) it would be a call similar to
`createIssue` except that you would call what the JIRA Rest API has defined above with the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Call to setFieldValue() method of IssueInputBuilder class. You need to pass custom ID of your epic link and the value(epic link which you had created).
Hope this will work.

```
IssueInputBuilder issueBuilder = null;
issueBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder(PRJCT_KEY,ISSUE_TYPE);
issueBuilder.setFieldValue(epicLinkId, epicLinkvalue);
```

else generate json as below and call to put() method over REST.

```
"\"" + customEpicLinkId + "\":" + "\"" + epicLinkValue + "\"";
```